# Extension in List limited to one Type

Tags: c#, list, extension-methods

is it possible to do an extension for a specific type of list?

Like a calculate function only for `List<int>`?

I tried something like

```
public static void addTag<TagInfos>(this List<TagInfos> list,
zeiterfassungsdatensatz ds){
 //some code
}
```

this. in this example i tried to create a extension addTag(zeiterfassungsdatensatz) to all `List<TagInfos>`. This function is usable at all my Lists. But i dont want this.

Is it possible?

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you don't need a generic extension:

```
public static void addTag(this List<TagInfos> list, zeiterfassungsdatensatz ds) 
{ 
    // ...
}
```

But you could also use a  constraint:

```
public static void addTag<T>(this List<T> list, zeiterfassungsdatensatz ds) 
    where T: TagInfos
{ 

}
```